# Excel loop error 3705

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code however each time i execute it, it returns a `Run-time error 3705`. I know it has something to do with the loop however am unable to figure it out.

```
Private Sub UpdateRecord()
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Dim i As Integer
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\temp\test.mdb"

cn.Open strConnection

For i = 1 To 10
strSql = "UPDATE table1 AS type SET type.Property='" & Range("D" & i).Value & "', type.Value='" & Range("E" & i).Value & "' WHERE PropertyID=1;"

Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

Next i

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Which specific line generates the error. Also, try `Debug.Print strSql` to see if you generate the correct string.

Comment: L42 - The error occurs at `Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)` once it increments to 2.

Comment: L42 - If i change `For i = 1 To 10` to `For i = 1 To 3` as there are only 3 rows of data, it works fine. Is there a way to check which row has the last set of values?

Comment: May be you should use Do-loop. e.g. `i = 1: Do Until IsEmpty(Range("D" & i)): strSql = "..." : Set rs = ...: i = i + 1: Loop` This will stop on the cell in Column D that is Empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specifically define your target range like this.

```
Dim rng As Range

With Thisworkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName")
    Set rng = .Range("D1", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Address)
End With

'~~> Rest of your code

For i = 1 to rng.Rows.Count
    '~~> Rest of your code here
Next
```

Something like this really but there can be various approaches.
It's really up to you, but this is the basic logic.